# Python read.csv in chunks leads to __exit__ error

Tags: python, pandas, chunks, read.csv

I have the following code which works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv

data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(r'C:\myfolder\test.csv', 
          header=True,
          encoding="utf-8-sig",
          index=False,
          sep=";",
          decimal=",",
          date_format="%d.%m.%Y",
          float_format='%.2f',
          quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

# Read it again and store it in a new file
with pd.read_csv(r'C:\myfolder\test.csv', sep=";", encoding="utf-8-sig", decimal=",", chunksize=1) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        chunk.to_csv(r'C:\myfolder\test_new.csv', mode='a', header=not os.path.exists(r'C:\myfolder\test_new.csv'),
                    encoding="utf-8-sig",
                    index=False,
                    sep=";",
                    decimal=",",
                    date_format="%d.%m.%Y",
                    float_format='%.2f',
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

It creates a simple dataframe and saves it to a csv. Then, I read this csv in chunk sizes and export it to a new file. The resulting file looks exactly the same with no problems:

```
Name;Age
Tom;20
nick;21
krish;19
jack;18
```

Now when I run it on another machine (Python 3.5.3), which uses pandas version 0.20.1 I get an `__exit__` error. I have no idea, why this error occurs?

I looked it up and pandas 0.20.1 indeed has the chunksize option. So it should work.

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM This is all I got. I ran it with the built-in Python implementation used by Caseware IDEA and I have no further message. This is the message which is displayed and it is a Python error, not IDEA. It is somehow connected to the problem that pandas is used in an older version.